# A sort of dual to nondegenerate random variables

Tags: pr.probability, convex-geometry, integral-geometry

I was motivated by this classical puzzle/1992 Putnam problem.

Suppose 4 points are independently and uniformly distributed on a sphere in 3d. What is the probability the tetrahedron they form contains the center?

The answer to the analogous problem with $d+1$ points in $d$-dimensions is $\frac{1}{2^d}$. There are various proofs ranging in cleverness.

I've run into the following idea while trying to generalize the situation.

Let $V$ be a topological vector space, equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Say a $V$ valued random variable $X$ is non-degenerate if, whenever $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_d$ with $d\leq \dim V$ are independent (as random variables) and $X$ distributed, then the set $\{X_1,\ldots,X_d\}$ is almost surely linearly independent. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ examples include the standard normal distribution, the uniform distribution on a set with nonzero volume, etc. Notice if $d\geq 2$ and $P[X=x]$ is nonzero for some $x$ then $X$ is degenerate.

Given a non-degenerate $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued random variable $X$, let $X=X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots,X_d$ be independent and $X$ distributed and for each $i$ consider the $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued random variable $X_i^*$ defined by

$$\langle X_i^*, X_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$$

where the brackets denote your favorite inner product, I'll use the dot product. Notice that $X_i^*\overset{d}{=}X_j^*$ due to i.i.d., and so we can think of this as transforming a single distribution $X$ to the dual $X^*$. Does this have a name already and can someone point me to a reference for it? I want to call it the dual transform of $X$ because we construct it with the dual basis to the $X_i$.

Some examples would be...

- If $d=1$ then $X^*=\frac{1}{X}$
- If $d=2$ and we have component random variables $X=(x,y)$, $X_i=(x_i,y_i)$, and $X^*=(x^*,y^*)$ then $$x^*\overset{d}{=}\frac{y_2}{x_1y_2-x_2y_1},y^*\overset{d}{=}\frac{-x_2}{x_1y_2-x_2y_1}$$
- In particular, If $X=(\cos(A),\sin(A))$ is uniformly distributed on $S^1$ then $X^*$ is distributed according to $$X^*=(\frac{\sin(B)}{\sin(B-A)},\frac{-\cos(B)}{\sin(B-A)}),$$ where $A,B$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$. This case is relevant for the motivating puzzle.
- More generally, if we pick an orthonormal basis and view the $X_i$ as column vectors with respect to this basis arranged into a random matrix, then $X^*$ would correspond to taking the inverse transposed of that matrix.

---

If you're wondering why I care about this and to spoil a solution of the motivating problem:

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{d+1}$ be i.i.d. nondegenerate $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued random variables. Consider the random variables $X_k^*$ constructed as above using the first $d$ of the $X_i$. Then the probability the convex hull of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{d+1}$ contains the origin is $$\prod_{k=1}^dP[\langle X_k^*,X_{d+1}\rangle\leq 0]= P[\langle X_1^*,X_{d+1}\rangle\leq 0]^d$$ which follows from the a.s. true $$X_{d+1}=\sum_{k=1}^d\langle X_k^*,X_{d+1}\rangle X_k$$

This solves the original puzzle and in fact gives you the result for any distribution which is rotationally symmetric around the origin.

---

I guess my first question beyond does this construction already have a name is if $X$ has some probability density function $f(x)$ is there an easy way to obtain the density of $X^*$?

Comment: (This looks interesting to me, I’m not sure why someone downvoted…)

Comment: The software has flagged this question for what it deems excessive edits. Please note that every edit bumps the question to the top of the front page, and repeatedly editing a question is generally frowned on if it goes on too many times. It would be better to do all the editing in one go, perhaps noting potential edits over the course of 24 hours and then make all the changes at once?

Comment: I was unaware that edits caused a bump to the top, my bad. I've edited all I need to and it shouldn't happen again.